# border radius in ie 8 using RoundRect

Tags: internet-explorer-8, css

I have a site which has a lot of corners. I don't want to have to go through it and apply special rules to the specific divs.

I came across RoundRect at https://github.com/csnover/RoundRect

Sounded like a great idea.

But i keep getting error : `Uncaught ReferenceError: RoundRect is not defined`

For an example of what i am trying to see i have put up an example on js fiddle :

http://jsfiddle.net/uzi002/YSVF3/1/

Comment: Your Fiddle triggers: `Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLDocument> has no method 'ready'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered using CSS3 PIE?

As I understand it, you had a single line to your CSS and the HTC file "enables" rounded corners in IE6+

http://css3pie.com/

Disclaimer - I'm in no way affiliated or associated with CSS3PIE or Sencha Labs

Comment: maybe an example if u culd edit my fiddle to see how to use this?

Comment: difficult to do as you need the .htc file but the css would end up looking like:

    .slidecontrol { 
    height:40px; 
    padding-top:0px; 
    margin-top:-1px; 
    background-color:#878A84; 
    width:100%; 
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    behavior: url(/css/PIE.htc);
    }
​
Of course you'd need to grab the PIE.htc file and upload it to your site.

Comment: erm ive done this and for some reason it turns the div background white

Comment: could you update your fiddle to reflect your new markup? Or link to a Pastebin / Gist / Similar?

Answer (score 0):

This [behaviour file](http://curved-corner.googlecode.com/files/border-radius.htc) could come in handy.

```
.slidecontrol {
    behavior: url(http://example.com/css/border-radius.htc);
}
```

Put the file in your css folder.